# C# Run a WSL command, wait to finish then exit

Tags: c#, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to use c# on windows to run a command on WSL, wait for it to finish then exit.

I have this so far:

```
            Process p = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "cmd.exe", RedirectStandardInput = true, UseShellExecute = false
            };
            p.StartInfo = info;
            p.Start();

            using StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput;
            if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(@"wsl cd /mnt/c/Users/john.doe/source/repos/BamProcessor/BamProcessor; samtools view -b -h -L tempbed.bed tempbam.bam > finalbam.bam; logout; exit;");
            }

            p.WaitForExit();
```

`p.WaitForExit()` seems to keep it open that my samtools process finishes, but my `logout; exit;` doesn't seem to cause it to ever exit and it waits on `p.WaitForExit()` forever.

How do I get it to both wait for my command to finish, but then actually exit and continue on with my C# code after?

Comment: hey Kyle, I know you beat me to the answer by couple of 10 seconds yesterday :D, may I ask if you can consider approving it. not a big deal even if you don't. Cheers !!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
using StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput;
if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
{
    sw.WriteLine(
    @"wsl cd /mnt/c/Users/kyle.traynor/source/repos/BamProcessor/BamProcessor; samtools view -b -h -L tempbed.bed tempbam.bam > finalbam.bam; exit");
    sw.WriteLine("exit");
    w.Close();
}

p.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `StandardInput` to check if the stream supports writing and use its *WriteLine()* method to write to it, after its done you can clear the buffer and close the *StreamWriter* respectively

```
if (process.StandardInput.BaseStream.CanWrite)
{
    process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"wsl cd /mnt/c/Users/john.doe/source/repos/BamProcessor/BamProcessor; samtools view -b -h -L tempbed.bed tempbam.bam > finalbam.bam; logout; exit;");
    process.StandardInput.Flush();
    process.StandardInput.Close();
}
```